# How to get KnowledgeableUser records for user via apex?

Tags: apex, chatter, knowledge

I have few guys knowledgeable about some topics in Chatter and i'm trying to retreive these records via Apex. But there're no found results at all in dev console or just controller.

How can I get these records?

Comment: What do you mean by knowledgeable ?

Comment: "Knows About" section in Chatter. It works with KnowledgeableUser object as far I understand.

Comment: Can you post what Apex code you have? You can query the KnowledgeableUser object in a SOQL. If you want to do this as a one-off exercise, you can use DataLoader or Apex Execute via Workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php

Comment: Just:
System.debug(
 [
        SELECT Id
        FROM KnowledgeableUser
    ]
);

Workbench didn't return any records.
Maybe there is an issue with some settings?

Chatter shows that I have such record: http://take.ms/Hukee

Comment: Go to Apex Execute in Workbench and execute: List<KnowledgeableUser> kuList = [SELECT Id FROM KnowledgeableUser]; 
system.debug('THE NUMBER OF KNOWLEDGEABLEUSER RECORDS IN THIS ORG ARE...' + ' ' + kuList.size());  How many records do you see?

Comment: Do current user have access to KnowledgeableUser object? Run the following lines in your test methods:
System.debug(KnowledgeableUser.sObjectType.getDescribe().isQueryable());
System.debug(KnowledgeableUser.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible());
System.debug(KnowledgeableUser.sObjectType.getDescribe().isSearchable());

Comment: Andy, it's zero.

Comment: Yuri, it's queryable, accesible but not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys...

It works now. As far I understand records were created after some time interval.

I think it's some standard Salesforce logic.